# php multiple lines text

Tags: php, html

I have a webserver running php it uses php config files to draw the main index.php page and im trying to clean it up a bit right now its like:

```
$config['p1'] = 'Line one text';
$config['p2'] = 'Line 2 text';
$config['p3'] = 'Line 3 text';
```

and on the index i have a lot of things like this:

```
echo $p1;
echo $p2;
echo $p3;
```

i want to clean this up a bit how can using my config files make it output multiple lines using one config text set like this but idk how exactly to do it

```
$config['p1] = 'this is text on line 1',
               'this is text on line 2',
               'this is final line of text';
```

so the output on the html page the user sees would look like

```
this is text on line 1
this is text on line 2
this is final line of text
```

but that doesnt work how can i do what im trying to do? or is it not possible with php the way i have it.

Comment: please correct your spelling. It is difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Pretty basic stuff here.  You need to use HTML line breaks if you want line breaks in HTML...

Comment: Please define clean up.

Comment: by clean up i mean i didnt want all the config p1 p2 p3 ect i wanted one p1 and output multiple lines on the page

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['p1] = 'this is text on line 1',
           'this is text on line 2',
           'this is final line of text';
```

Is wrong syntax: PHP does not understand. It should be

```
$config['p1'] = 'this is text on line 1'."<br>\n".
           'this is text on line 2'."<br>\n".
           'this is final line of text';
```

The `.` operator concatenates strings.
Alternatively, you can write:

```
$config['p1'] = 'this is text on line 1<br>
           this is text on line 2<br>
           this is final line of text';
```

because in PHP, a string can be on multiple lines.

To output the string, use

```
echo $config['p1']
```

Comment: this didnt work for me it just put it all on one line on my index page where echo $config['p1'] is at. like this:  this is text on line one <br> this is text on line 2.... ect  it actually printed <br> on the page the user sees